# Table caption not appearing in PNAS document class

Tags: floats, captions, templates, pnas

I am unable to get table captions to show up when using the [PNAStwo document class](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/pnas) from 2008 (the latest version includes printer marks that I do not want).

The documentation says "*Figure and table captions should be entered at the end of the document...*" but as captions *are* shown for figures, I'd like them to be shown for tables too.

I was hoping their recommendation wasn't implemented as a limit for authors but it seems it is, or am I missing something? If not, is there a workaround I can employ?

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pnastwoF}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{article}

\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        1 & 2 \\
        3 & 4
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{A caption that does not appear.}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{A caption that does appear.}
\end{figure}

\end{article}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add a link to where the class file can be downloaded, it is not on CTAN.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Apologies for that, the link to the particular version I'm using is as follows: [PNAS](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/pnas)

Comment: What happens if you put the `\caption` before the `tabular`, instead of afterwards? (cf the example file in your link)

Comment: @alexwlchan It does not change the behavior unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue.  (It's really annoying when trying to produce print-quality preprint versions of the paper.) Poking around in pnastwo.cls, I found the following fix:

Find the first line in pnastwo.cls which says

```
\ifx\@captype\xtable
```

Change this to

```
\ifx\@captype\table
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to touch the class file, you can
put the following into the preamble of your document:

```
% Fix wierd behavior which prevents table captions from appearing for
% tables in the body of the article
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
\ifx\@captype\table
\let\currtabcaption\relax
\gdef\currtabcaption{
\tabnumfont\relax #1. \tabtextfont\relax#2\par
\vskip\belowcaptionskip 
}
\else
 \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\fignumfont#1.\figtextfont\hskip.5em\relax #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
\fignumfont\relax #1.\figtextfont\hskip.5em\relax#2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
\fi
}
\makeatother
```

One additional comment: once this bug is fixed, you'll almost certainly run into another issue which you'd want fixed if you use the PNAS two-column class to produce production-quality output: Unless you define floats with the h "here" placement, it loses the labels, so all cross-referencing of figures and tables breaks.  Here is the fix, for direct pasting into the document preamble.  You can also patch up the macro \DonormalEndcol pnastwo.cls, it's the same mistake 6 times over...

```
% And another fix.  PNAS class loses the label of floats unless they       
% were defined with the [h] option (so not really floats at all).  It      
% all comes down to wrong scope in the following routine which pushes      
% out the floats onto the page.  This is the fixed version:        
\makeatletter                                  
\def\DonormalEndcol{%                              
%% top float ==>                               
\ifx\toporbotfloat\xtopfloat%                          
%% figure ==>                                  
  \ifcaptypefig%                               
  \expandafter\gdef\csname topfloat\the\figandtabnumber\endcsname{%    
  \vbox{\vskip\PushOneColTopFig%                       
  \unvbox\csname figandtabbox\the\loopnum\endcsname%               
  \vskip\abovefigcaptionskip%                          
  \csname caption\the\loopnum\endcsname%                   
  \csname letteredcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname%               
  \csname continuedcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname%              
  \csname letteredcontcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname            
  \ifredefining%                               
  \csname label\the\loopnum\endcsname%                     
  \expandafter\gdef\csname topfloat\the\loopnum\endcsname{}\fi}%       
  \vskip\intextfloatskip%%                         
  \vskip-4pt %% probably an artifact of topskip??              
}%                                     
\else%                                     
%% plate ==>                                   
  \ifcaptypeplate%                             
  \expandafter\gdef\csname topfloat\the\figandtabnumber\endcsname{%    
  \vbox{\vskip\PushOneColTopFig%                       
  \unvbox\csname figandtabbox\the\loopnum\endcsname            
  \vskip\abovefigcaptionskip                           
  \csname caption\the\loopnum\endcsname                    
  \csname letteredcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname                
  \csname continuedcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname               
  \csname letteredcontcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname            
  \ifredefining                                
  \csname label\the\loopnum\endcsname                      
  \expandafter\gdef\csname topfloat\the\loopnum\endcsname{}\fi}        
  \vskip\intextfloatskip %%                            
  \vskip-4pt %% probably an artifact of topskip??              
}%                                     
\else% table ==>                               
 \expandafter\gdef\csname topfloat\the\figandtabnumber\endcsname{%     
 \vbox{\vskip\PushOneColTopTab %%                      
 \csname caption\the\loopnum\endcsname                     
  \csname letteredcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname                
  \csname continuedcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname               
  \csname letteredcontcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname            
  \vskip\captionskip                               
  \unvbox\csname figandtabbox\the\loopnum\endcsname            
\ifredefining                                  
\csname label\the\loopnum\endcsname                    
\expandafter\gdef\csname topfloat\the\loopnum\endcsname{}\fi           
}\vskip\intextfloatskip %% why don't we need this?             
\vskip-10pt}                                   
\fi\fi%                                    
%                                      
\else% bottom float                            
%                                      
\ifcaptypefig                                  
\expandafter\gdef\csname botfloat\the\figandtabnumber\endcsname{%      
\vskip\intextfloatskip                             
\vbox{\unvbox\csname figandtabbox\the\loopnum\endcsname            
\vskip\abovefigcaptionskip                         
  \csname caption\the\loopnum\endcsname                    
  \csname letteredcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname%               
  \csname continuedcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname%              
  \csname letteredcontcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname%               
\vskip\PushOneColBotFig%%                          
\ifredefining%                                 
\csname label\the\loopnum\endcsname                    
\expandafter\gdef\csname botfloat\the\loopnum\endcsname{}\fi}}%        
\else                                      
\ifcaptypeplate                                
\expandafter\gdef\csname botfloat\the\figandtabnumber\endcsname{%      
\vskip\intextfloatskip                             
\vbox{\unvbox\csname figandtabbox\the\loopnum\endcsname            
\vskip\abovefigcaptionskip                         
  \csname caption\the\loopnum\endcsname                    
  \csname letteredcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname%               
  \csname continuedcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname%              
  \csname letteredcontcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname%               
\vskip\PushOneColBotFig%%                          
\ifredefining%                                 
\csname label\the\loopnum\endcsname                    
\expandafter\gdef\csname botfloat\the\loopnum\endcsname{}\fi}}%        
  \else% TABLE                                 
\expandafter\gdef\csname botfloat\the\figandtabnumber\endcsname{%      
  \vskip\intextfloatskip                           
\vbox{\csname caption\the\loopnum\endcsname                
  \csname letteredcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname                
  \csname continuedcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname               
  \csname letteredcontcaption\the\loopnum\endcsname%               
  \vskip.5\intextfloatskip                         
  \unvbox\csname figandtabbox\the\loopnum\endcsname%               
\vskip\PushOneColBotTab                            
\ifredefining%                                 
\csname label\the\loopnum\endcsname                    
\expandafter\gdef\csname botfloat\the\loopnum\endcsname{}\fi}}%        
\fi\fi\fi}                                 
\makeatother
```

Comment: I started using this, however it changes the style of the table caption.

Answer (score 2):

The template file that's distributed along with the class says

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%       FIGURES AND TABLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%% Adding Figure and Table References
%% Be sure to add figures and tables after \end{article}
%% and before \end{document}
```

Here's the example:

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pnastwoF} % this is not required
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\title{X}
\author{A. Uthor\affil{1}{University of Nowhere}}

\contributor{Submitted to Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences
of the United States of America}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\maketitle % The \maketitle command is necessary to build the title page

\begin{article}

\lipsum

\end{article}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{A caption that appears.}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{A caption that does appear.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the table caption is typeset with the same width as the `tabular` environment. Why? I don't know.

Comment: But I'd prefer to have my tables in the report itself, not at the end of it. I'd prefer to then have my captions shown where that table appears.

Comment: @Doggie52 then use a different class. This class is made to the requirements of a specific journal. If you are not submitting to that journal, use a different class. They made the class, their rules.

Comment: @daleif Fair enough, point taken. I am just so happy with how the rest of the report is laid out with the class. If I can stick to using that class I would very much like to.

Besides, it would be interesting to learn how these "rules" regarding captions are set-up from within a class.