# Table title and notes not appearing in PNAS

Tags: tables, siunitx, pnas

I'm trying to prepare a manuscript for [PNAS](http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/latex.xhtml) and am running into issues with a table. As in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237791/table-ref-not-displaying-in-pnas-format) question/answer, the table is placed after the `\end{article}`. However, when compiling the document, the table title still isn't shown, nor are `\tablenote`s. I've narrowed it down to the `siunits` package, which I used and when removing it (and all uses of `\SI`) I get the title back. I would prefer to keep using `siunits`. Is there a way around this or should I start a Word document (ok, empty threat)?

```
\documentclass{pnastwo}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx} % makes the table screwed up...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\title{Paper title}

\author{Avi Ginsburg \affil{1}{Somewhere over the rainbow}}

\contributor{Submitted to Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences
        of the United States of America}

\significancetext{Quite insignificant.}

\maketitle

\begin{article}
    \begin{abstract}
    {
        abstract (adjective) existing in thought or as an idea but not having a physical or concrete existence.
    }
    \end{abstract}

    \dropcap{H}ello world. Small is $\SI{1}{\angstrom}$ or so.

    \begin{acknowledgments}
        We are grateful to egreg for expressing sympathy for those who have to use the PNAS class.
    \end{acknowledgments}

    \end{article}

    \begin{table*}[ht]
        %   \centering
        \caption{Table title - We like to see them}
        \begin{tabular}{c c c }
            \toprule
            &
            \textbf{Something} & \textbf{Else} \\ 
            & & \\ 
            \midrule
            \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Random}}
            &   accidental\tablenote{this is a table note} &  \\ 
            &   aimless & \\ 
            &   arbitrary & \\ 
            &   incidental & \\ 
            \cmidrule{2-3}
            &   indiscriminate & \\ 
            &   irregular & \\ 
            \midrule
            \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Example}}
            & case & \\ 
            & illustration&\\ 
            & lesson &\\ 
            \cmidrule{2-3}
            & object & \\ 
            & part & \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tbl}
    \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

I tried adding [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165920/table-caption-not-appearing-in-pnas-document-class/166722#166722) answer to the preamble and changing the class file. This helps somewhat, as the title/caption is shown, however the style is changed and `\tablenote`s are still not shown below the table.

Comment: No real solution, but try `\captionof{table}{....}` (load the `caption` package!) -- it works with `siunitx` then too, but I have no clue where the culprit is

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the problem then becomes that the style is wrong as well as the placement of the table. There is definitely something in siunitx that the class doesn't like. The `caption` package also gives you a warning about incompatible class.

Comment: Using `\RequirePackage{siunitx}` before the `\documentclass{...}` works better but then the space between the cells in the table gets squashed

Comment: The problem here isn't `siunitx` _per se_, it's the (standard) `array` package. The latter is used by `siunitx` to extend the tabular syntax. As `array` is part of the base LaTeX distribution, the class here is _badly_ defective.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the class is not compatible with `array`. This means either PNAS or `siunitx`, not both.

Comment: @egreg That was what I had feared. As I need to send it to PNAS, I replaced `siunitx` with a few commands in the preamble and `unit`.